# Nativescript RadDataForm Extremely Slow Load

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

My project is using RadDataForm and one issue I'm having is the transition to the page with the form on it takes forever. 5-10 seconds sometimes, which is ridiculous. Not realistic to use. Is there anyway I can speed that up? Can I transition to the page first then load the form?

My code is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786055/nativescript-raddataform-multilinetext-not-working-on-android) from another issue.

Comment: I'm not encountering such issues on my end, would you mind creating a playground sample where that delay can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

not sure but change **add-store.model.ts** to **add-store-model.ts** and write result please.(for add-store.component.html too)

In fact I haven't seen any info that we shouldn't use **"."** until file extensions in NS docs. We will see is its cause that or not

Comment: File names really doesn't matter, moreover that is you mostly name files in Angular projects.